# Getting a One-to-One Relation to work in Azure Appservice using EF Code First

Tags: xamarin.forms, ef-code-first, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I am having a hard time getting this to work, so maybe you can help me out here.

**Technologies used**

- Xamarin.Forms
- Azure App Service
- Azure SQL
- AzureMobileServices (MobileServiceClient, MobileServer)
- Entity Framework Code First

**Introduction**

My Xamarin.Forms app is used by users with both a billing and a delivery address. The database scheme looks like this:

**Users**

- Id
- BillingAddress_Id
- DeliveryAddress_Id

**Addresses**

- Id
- User_Id

When adding new addresses, I basically do something like that:

```
var user = await userService.GetUserByIdAsync(...);

var billingAddress = new Address
{
  UserId = user.Id,
  …
};

var deliveryAddress = new Address
{
  UserId = user.Id,
  …
}

user.BillingAddress = billingAddress;
user.DeliveryAddress = deliveryAddress;

await addressService.AddNewAddressAsync(billingAddress);
await addressService.AddNewAddressAsync(deliveryAddress);

await userService.UpdateUser(user);
```

**AddNewAddressAsync** is a service method that eventually makes the underlying repository create a new address like this:

```
public async Task<Address> CreateAsync(Address item)
{
  await Addresses.InsertAsync(item);
  return item;
}
```

With **Addresses** being an instance of the IMobileServiceTable interface instantiated like this:

```
private IMobileServiceTable<Address> Addresses
{
  get
  {
    var table = App.Client.GetTable<Address>();

    table.MobileServiceClient.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling =     
      Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;

    return table;
  }
}
```

**UpdateUser** on the other hand is supposed to patch the existing user by triggering the underlying repository like this:

```
public async Task<User> PatchAsync(User item)
{
  await Users.UpdateAsync(item);
  return item;
}
```

With **Users** also being an instance of the IMobileServiceTable interface instantiated the very same way as **Addresses** before:

```
private IMobileServiceTable<User> Users
{
  get
  {
    var table = App.Client.GetTable<User>();    

    table.MobileServiceClient.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = 
      Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;

    return table;
  }
}
```

On server side, this is what the controllers do:

**AddressController**

```
[Authorize]
public class AddressController : TableController<Address>
{
  protected override void Initialize(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
  {
    base.Initialize(controllerContext);
    var context = new AppContext();
    DomainManager = new EntityDomainManager<Address>(context, Request);
  }

  public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostAddress(Address address)
  {
    Address current = await InsertAsync(address);
    return CreatedAtRoute("Tables", new { id = current.Id }, current);
  }

  ...
}
```

**UserController**

```
[Authorize]
public class UserController : TableController<User>
{
  protected override void Initialize(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
  {
    base.Initialize(controllerContext);
    var context = new AppContext();
    DomainManager = new EntityDomainManager<User>(context, Request);
  }

  public Task<User> PatchUser(string id, Delta<User> patch)
  {
    return UpdateAsync(id, patch);
  }

  …
}
```

Here is what is logged when executing the above code:

**Insertion of the first address**

Request: POST http://localhost:51546/tables/Address
{"$id":"1","id":null,...,"UserId":"8953d3deb9b2459796aa00f43d7416cb","User":null}
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Request, Method=POST, Url=http://localhost:51546/tables/Address, Message='http://localhost:51546/tables/Address'
...
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Message='Model state is valid. Values: address=SpenceAppService.DataObjects.Address', Operation=HttpActionBinding.ExecuteBindingAsync
...
INSERT [dbo].[Addresses]([Id], [UserId], ...)
VALUES (@0, @1, ...)
SELECT ...
FROM [dbo].[Addresses]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [Id] = @0
-- @0: '2a407222f6984052b90d233fa9935286' (Type = String, Size = 128)
-- @1: '8953d3deb9b2459796aa00f43d7416cb' (Type = String, Size = 128)
...
-- Executing asynchronously at 23.05.2019 13:22:10 +02:00
-- Completed in 7 ms with result: SqlDataReader

Committed transaction at 23.05.2019 13:22:11 +02:00
Closed connection at 23.05.2019 13:22:11 +02:00
...
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Response, Status=201 (Created), Method=POST, Url=http://localhost:51546/tables/Address, Message='Content-type='application/json; charset=utf-8', content-length=unknown'
...
Response: Created
{"userId":"8953d3deb9b2459796aa00f43d7416cb",...,"id":"2a407222f6984052b90d233fa9935286",...}

**Insertion of the second address**

Request: POST http://localhost:51546/tables/Address
{"$id":"1","id":null,...,"UserId":"8953d3deb9b2459796aa00f43d7416cb","User":null}
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Request, Method=POST, Url=http://localhost:51546/tables/Address, Message='http://localhost:51546/tables/Address'
...
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Message='Model state is valid. Values: address=SpenceAppService.DataObjects.Address', Operation=HttpActionBinding.ExecuteBindingAsync
...
INSERT [dbo].[Addresses]([Id], [UserId], ...)
VALUES (@0, @1, ...)
SELECT ...
FROM [dbo].[Addresses]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [Id] = @0
-- @0: 'a56e1ca3a7b341a39bc00d22772e39e5' (Type = String, Size = 128)
-- @1: '8953d3deb9b2459796aa00f43d7416cb' (Type = String, Size = 128)
...
-- Executing asynchronously at 23.05.2019 13:22:11 +02:00
-- Completed in 0 ms with result: SqlDataReader

Committed transaction at 23.05.2019 13:22:11 +02:00
Closed connection at 23.05.2019 13:22:11 +02:00
...
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Response, Status=201 (Created), Method=POST, Url=http://localhost:51546/tables/Address, Message='Content-type='application/json; charset=utf-8', content-length=unknown'
...
Response: Created
{"userId":"8953d3deb9b2459796aa00f43d7416cb",...,"id":"a56e1ca3a7b341a39bc00d22772e39e5",...}

**Patch of the user**

Request: PATCH http://localhost:51546/tables/User/8953d3deb9b2459796aa00f43d7416cb
{"$id":"1","id":"8953d3deb9b2459796aa00f43d7416cb",...,"BillingAddress":{"$id":"7","id":"2a407222f6984052b90d233fa9935286",...,"UserId":"8953d3deb9b2459796aa00f43d7416cb","User":null},"DeliveryAddress":{"$id":"8","id":"a56e1ca3a7b341a39bc00d22772e39e5",...,"UserId":"8953d3deb9b2459796aa00f43d7416cb","User":null}}
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Request, Method=PATCH, Url=http://localhost:51546/tables/User/8953d3deb9b2459796aa00f43d7416cb, Message='http://localhost:51546/tables/User/8953d3deb9b2459796aa00f43d7416cb'
...
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Message='Model state is valid. Values: id=8953d3deb9b2459796aa00f43d7416cb, patch=System.Web.Http.OData.Delta`1[SpenceAppService.DataObjects.User]', Operation=HttpActionBinding.ExecuteBindingAsync
...
Opened connection asynchronously at 23.05.2019 13:22:30 +02:00
SELECT 
    ... 
    [Limit1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    ...
    [Limit1].[BillingAddress_Id] AS [BillingAddress_Id], 
    [Limit1].[DeliveryAddress_Id] AS [DeliveryAddress_Id]
    FROM ( SELECT TOP (1) 
        [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
        ...
        [Extent1].[BillingAddress_Id] AS [BillingAddress_Id], 
        [Extent1].[DeliveryAddress_Id] AS [DeliveryAddress_Id]
        FROM [dbo].[Users] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE [Extent1].[Id] = @p__linq__0
    )  AS [Limit1]
-- p__linq__0: '8953d3deb9b2459796aa00f43d7416cb' (Type = String, Size = 4000)
...

INSERT [dbo].[Addresses]([Id], [UserId], ...)
VALUES (@0, @1, ...)
SELECT ...
FROM [dbo].[Addresses]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [Id] = @0
-- @0: '2a407222f6984052b90d233fa9935286' (Type = String, Size = 128)
-- @1: '8953d3deb9b2459796aa00f43d7416cb' (Type = String, Size = 128)
...
-- Executing asynchronously at 23.05.2019 13:22:30 +02:00
-- Failed in 1 ms with error: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_dbo.Addresses'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Addresses'. The duplicate key value is (2a407222f6984052b90d233fa9935286).
The statement has been terminated.
...
The request could not be completed.  (Conflict)

**Problem**

As you can see, while patching the user, the underlying method tries to also insert the addresses that actually have already been inserted, so the error message does perfectly make sense.

However, how do I get this to work?

When I don't insert the addresses first, they don't get ids from the server, so when the userService patches the user which in turn tries to insert the addresses (which then don't exist yet), I get an error message telling me, that the Id field (of the address) is required.

When I add Id fields for both **BillingAddress** and **DeliveryAddress** to the user object and skip setting the address fields before updating the user but set their respective ids instead (after inserting the addresses), everything works as expected.

However, I still seem to be missing the üoint, because I thought, Entity Framework should be able to handle all of this internally.

I do know, that working with Azure Appservice, Entity Framework, Code First, an ASP.NET MVC backend and dependent tables accessed by using the Azure Mobile Apps Client and Server API makes things different,... but I was not able to find samples that clearly show how to get this just right...

I also read about having to configure relations either by using fluent API or by decorating properties. However, even when doing nothing, it seems to me as if the framework is able to handle this by itself. For instance when adding the BillingAddressId property to the user data object on server side and executing an Add-Migration, the migration code contains foreign key constraints without me having to explicitly configure them:

```
public override void Up()
{
  AddColumn("dbo.Users", "BillingAddressId", c => c.String(maxLength: 128));
  AddColumn("dbo.Users", "DeliveryAddressId", c => c.String(maxLength: 128));
  CreateIndex("dbo.Users", "BillingAddressId");
  CreateIndex("dbo.Users", "DeliveryAddressId");
  AddForeignKey("dbo.Users", "BillingAddressId", "dbo.Addresses", "Id");
  AddForeignKey("dbo.Users", "DeliveryAddressId", "dbo.Addresses", "Id");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're User entities aren't aware of the Address objects that were added to the DB. What you want to do is `var entity = context.Users.Find(id);` and update `entity` with what's in `patch` using either `entity.Prop = patch.Prop;` or using something like Automapper to update the entity and then call your `UpdateAsync`. This will make the context aware of the new changes made to your `User` entity and will have the foreign keys populated.

Hope this helps.

Comment: According to the source of Microsofts Azure Mobile Server SDK, this is what UpdateAsync method called in my UserController is supposed to do: https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-server/blob/70d8f2352b2112453e934bf874ce748111c5841c/src/Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.Entity/EntityDomainManager.cs#L255

Wait… except, that it doesn't neccessarily seem to expand relations as I do on my own side… I'll check that.